# Server Only Respond to certain Posts (Security)

Tags: security, http

Ok I have 0 experience in anything dealing with security, so I need a little guidance. I have two servers that communicate through HTTP request. I want to make sure the servers only execute requests that come from one another. I have no idea how to block out other requests or verify that a request is real. I just need someone to tell me what direction to head in to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of things to ensure that only these two servers and no-one else *talks* to them

1. **Port blocking**- Have only one port open on each server to listen on. This port is unknown to other users so they cant communicate with any of your servers.
2. **IP blocking**- This is probably the safest method. Block any incoming requests which dont match the IP of your other server
3. **Mutual Authentication** - Theres a bunch of Mutual authentication algorithms available. Use one of them to ensure that the server youre talking to is your other server and nothing else
4. **Miscellaneous**- Key Sharing, Public Key Cryptography, Digital Signatures etc..

TBH this question is a bit too broad to answer in detail. You will have to do  the research on these methods and figure out which one best suites your usecase.